# Is there a way to detect text browsers using PHP?

Tags: php, browser, mobile

I want to serve mobile content for text browsers or browsers without CSS support. Is this possible using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's the native function get_browser, that returns a bunch of information based on the $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] variable.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: You need an up-to-date browsecap.ini file tho. =\

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the http `User-Agent` header via the php global `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. Of course you'll need to know what `User-Agent`s to look for... You could start by searching here: http://www.user-agents.org/

Answer (score 0):

There aren't that many text based browsers. (I'm using w3m, and then there's only lynx, links, elinks; [the others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text-based_web_browser) are mostly historic.)

But as a more deterministic alternative (however: cookie dependency!) you could *build a trap*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet trap" ref="ping-css.php">
```

Which simply updates a session or cookie value to check later:

```
<?php setcookie("css_supported", "yay"); ?> #faux-css { }
```

A note of concern would be that screenreaders (which are quasi text browsers too) also can consume CSS declarations. And some variants of `elinks` do too. But then again, you could built a more elaborate trap using `@media tty` or check via `@media screen` if it's a graphical browser.